# NGRX effects - dispatched actions are not executed in order

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-effects

Issue is that the dispatched actions are not executed in order . Below is my code .
Please suggest what changes needs to be done to make the dispatched actions execute in order

```
@Effect()
  NTSPrintOrder$: Observable<any> = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(listOrderActions.NTSPrintAll),
    withLatestFrom(this.store$.select(state => state['listorder'])),
   mergeMap(([action, listOrderState]: any) => {
      let obs =[];
      var orders =  listOrderState.listOrders.filter(x => x.selected)
      orders.forEach(order => {
         obs.push(listOrderActions.editOrder({'payload': {order_number : order.order_number}}))
         obs.push(listOrderActions.loadNTSDocument())
      });

      obs.push(listOrderActions.printNTSDocument())

      return obs;
    })
  )
}
```

Comment: What's the order you would expect?

Comment: first need to loop over items,  loadNTSdocument should wait for editorder to complete. After loop is finished it should execute printNTSdocument

Answer (score 0):

You should only dispatch `editOrder` within `NTSPrintAll`. The effect of `editOrder` then dispatches `loadNTSDocument` and the effect of `loadNTSDocument` dispatches `printNTSDocument`.